# После подключения ssl сертификата на сайт вышла ошибка яндекс денег

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

После подключения ssl сертификата на сайт вышла ошибка яндекс денег. Сайт работает на https

Yandex.Money PHP SDK sample app
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'YM_ApiConnectionError' with message 'Could not verify Yandex.Money's SSL certificate. Please make sure that your network is not intercepting certificates. (Network error: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.)' in /var/www/html/site.ru/module/payments/ya/lib/YandexMoney/ApiRequestor.php:96 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/site.ru/module/payments/ya/lib/YandexMoney/ApiRequestor.php(51): YM_ApiRequestor->_handleCurlError(60, 'Peer's Certific...') #1 /var/www/html/site.ru/module/payments/ya/lib/YandexMoney/ApiRequestor.php(16): YM_ApiRequestor->_curlRequest('https://sp-mone...', 'grant_type=auth...') #2 /var/www/html/site.ru/module/payments/ya/lib/YandexMoney.php(58): YM_ApiRequestor->request('https://sp-mone...', 'grant_type=auth...') #3 /var/www/html/site.ru/module/payments/money_yandex.php(42): YandexMoney->receiveOAuthToken('1BBDD393EC8CAB7...', 'http://site...', '7D99A685DFE6CF4...') #4 /var/www/html/site.ru/index.php(143): include('/var/www/html/w...') # in /var/www/html/site.ru/module/payments/ya/lib/YandexMoney/ApiRequestor.php on line 96

Comment: А что пишет в логах?

Comment: Не может распознать издателя сертификата. Возможно у вас используется самоподписанный сертификат

Comment: Нет, сертификаты покупные, Comodo PositiveSSL. По логам не знаю где смотреть, в стандартной папке /var/log не вижу